# .itmstransporter in home directory safe to delete? - Mac

Tags: itmstransporter

I am doing a cleanup on my Mac and noticed that my home directory contains a `.itmstransporter/` directory. From a quick search it shows that it's related to iTunes connect but I could not find anything on whether it is safe to delete or not.

There are a few versions in the directory `1.8.9`, `1.9.0`, etc...

Can I delete this directory safely? Will it regenerate it back later on?

Answer (score 3):

This directory contains settings and libraries ([Java JARs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format))) for the [iTMSTransporter program](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/). If deleted the directory will be created automatically the next time `iTMSTransporter` runs.

Generally you can safely delete this directory. If you have used a program or utility to interact with iTunes Connect, there's a possibility that it's saving some settings here. There is/was a `~/.itmstransporter/Defaults.properties` that controlled `iTMSTransporter` defaults, but as far as I know there's no explicit way to set these other than an external program or editing the file.